# how to subtract a column to the other colums in a data frame

Tags: r, frame, subtraction, ncdf4

I have a data frame that consist of 1000 rows and 156 columns. I'm trying to subtract the first column to the next 38 columns, then subtract column 39 to the next 38, and so, but I can't find a way to do it. I'm only using ncdf4 and nothing else. Something like this

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
1   2   3   4   5   6   4   5
3   4   6   5   4   3   2   7
```

And I'd like it to be

```
C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0   1   2   3   4   5   3   4
0   1   3   2   1   0  -1   4
```

The logic would be 
First 38 columns - First column

Columns 39:77 - Column 39

and so on.

Comment: What's the logic behind this subtraction?

Comment: First 38 columns - First column
then 
Columns 39:77 - Column 39 and so on

Comment: Got it! Edit your question to make this clearer.

Comment: Why doesn't the second block range from 39 to 76?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply doing

```
{
  z[,1:38] <- z[,1:38]-z[,1]
  z[,39:77] <-z[,39:77]-z[,39]
  z[,78:118] <-z[,78:118]-z[,78]
  z[,119:156] <-z[,119:156]-z[,119]
}
```

Where z is the dataframe. Might not be the nicest way but it did the trick

Comment: Check my answer and see if it helps. For loops are generally not the best though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a user defined function: You can add else if statements as desired.

```
mydiff<-function(df){
  mydiff<-df
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    if(i<=38){
      mydiff[,i]<-df[,i]-df[,1]
    }
    else if(i%in%c(39:77)){
      mydiff[,i]<-df[,i]-df[,39]
    }

    }

mydiff 
}

mydiff(df1)
```

Output:

```
 C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
 0  1  2  3  4  5  3  4
 0  1  3  2  1  0 -1  4
```

Benchmark:

```
system.time(result<-as.tibble(iris2) %>% 
              select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
              mydiff())
```

Result:

```
 user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following without any loop:

```
# sample data frame
df <- data.frame(matrix(data = seq(1,316),ncol = 158))

# split the data frame into list of data frame having columns
# 1 to 38, 39 to 77 and so on
df <- split.default(df, gl(round(ncol(df)/38),k = 38))

# subtract the last column from each
df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(df, function(f) f - f[,ncol(f)]))
colnames(df) <- paste0('C', seq(1,158))

print(head(df))

   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
1 -74 -72 -70 -68 -66
2 -74 -72 -70 -68 -66
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `tidyverse` to solve this, loading a package into R does little to the overhead of your environment and can make your life much easier.

```
 library(tidyverse)

> df %>% 
   mutate_at(.vars = vars(num_range(prefix = 'C', 1:38)), .funs = function(x) x - .$C1) %>% 
   mutate_at(.vars = vars(num_range(prefix = 'C', 39:77)), .funs = function(x) x - .$C39)

  C1 C2 C3 C4 C38 C39 C40 C41 C42 C77
1  0  1  2  3   4   0   1   2   3   4
2  0  0  3  2   4   0   0   3   2   4
```

**Data**

```
df <-
data.frame(
  C1 = c(1, 3),
  C2 = c(2, 3),
  C3 = c(3, 6),
  C4 = c(4, 5),
  C38 = c(5, 7),
  C39 = c(1, 3),
  C40 = c(2, 3),
  C41 = c(3, 6),
  C42 = c(4, 5),
  C77 = c(5, 7)
)
```